# Use Angular templating in content which is injected using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an Angular (4) template which injects what I give it using `[innerHTML]`, and this cannot be changed as it's an external package. So originally I had something like this:

```
public getMessages(): InterfaceName {
    return {
        emptyMessage: `<span>Some content!</span>`
    }
}
```

I then passed this into the template of the external element:

```
<external-element [messages]="this.getMessages()"></external-element>
```

This worked perfectly. However, the product I am working on needs to support internationalisation, so the strings all need to come from a separate JSON file, and Angular's `TranslateService` is used to retrieve the strings and render them. So in the internationalisation file, I had an array of messages which would each be posted to the `emptyMessage` object above. So I had this:

```
public getMessages(): InterfaceName {
    const messages = this.translate.instant('PATH.TO.JSON.STRINGS');
    return {
        emptyMessage: `
            <div>
                <span *ngFor="let message of messages;">{{ message }}</span>
            </div>`
    }
}
```

However, this just rendered {{ message }}, presumably due to introducing the possibility of an XSS attack, Angular sanitised the HTML. I also tried to use `[innerHTML]="message"` but this just showed up blank.

So how can I get the content from the i18n file and render it, after which the content is injected using `innerHTML`, of which I have no control?

Comment: This works only when you add the HTML to a template of a component. If you need this dynamic, you need to compile the component at runtime. There are tons of similar questions. Search for `[angular] $compile`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks Gunter, will look into it

Comment: read [Here is what you need to know about dynamic components in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e), specifically [Creating components on the fly](https://blog.angularindepth.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e#2b99) part